How to efficiently count the number of topological sorts of a directed subgraph of the square grid graph?
To compute the amount of topological sorts of a directed graph is a #P-complete problem, therefore, at least just as hard as an NP-complete problem. But how about for grid subgraphs? Can we solve this particular case in polynomial time?
Grid subgraphs (subgraphs of the square grid graph) form a very well behaved structure and can be often dealt with efficiently regarding general graph problems. For instance, the counting of perfect matchings is another #P-complete problem, but it can be solved in polynomial time for grid subgraphs with linear algebra techniques. This motivates my question.
Here are some properties that demonstrate the good behavior of a graph $G$ in this class of graphs

$G$ is planar.
$G$ is bipartite.
$\max\deg G\le 4$.
$\min\deg G\le 2$.


The counting of perfect matchings on grid subgraphs is thoroughly explored in this video. It relies on representing the graph as a bipartite adjacency matrix with $i$s instead of $1$s for vertical edges. This makes me think one could use a sign to further represent the edge's direction. However, I'm not sure of the properties of such a representation. In fact, this seems to lead to inconvenient interactions between vertical and horizontal edges.
Useful links:

This answer provides the insights of an $O(n2^n)$ algorithm for computing the number of topological sorts of a graph on $n$ vertices, which is already much better then the naive $O(n!)$ approach of iterating over every possible ordering.
This paper provides an $O(n^{t+4})$ algorithm for computing the number of topological sorts of a graph on $n$ vertices with treewidth of $t$. The $m\times n$ grid graph have treewidth of $\min(m, n)$, so this gives us an $O(n^{\sqrt n+4})$ algorithm (this is already sub-exponential).


How are you making the grid graph directed?

@MishaLavrov randomly choosing a direction for each edge.
